# event.setParam not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightninginput

Below is my code. My requirement is I want to uncheck a checkbox from the javascript controller based on some conditions. This is my code; HTML part

```
<lightning:input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"
                                                    name="{!salesorderndex+','+index}"
                                                    checked="{!lineitem.isLineItemChecked}"
                                                    onchange="{!c.selectlineitem}" ariaLabel="{!index}" />
```

and my javascript controller

```
selectlineitem: function (component, event, helper) {

var booleanCheck=true;
if(booleanCheck){
 event.preventDefault();
 event.setParam("checked", false);
}
```

but this is not working and not unchecking checkbox on UI

Comment: Try setting '!lineitem.isLineItemChecked' to false

Comment: I have tried that as well; it's not working

Comment: It should be event.target.setParam("checked",false);

Comment: no; as per the documentation of aura; it should be event.setParam("checked", false). Still, I have tried your suggestion and it's giving exception lightning error

Comment: [Edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/336244/edit) your question to include the exception you are getting.

Comment: @TSmith They're not getting an exception, presumably, but what they're doing isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the parameter won't do anything; that's for firing events to a different component/handler.

What you're trying to do is update the checkbox. To do this, you need to update your data model.

```
selectlineitem: function(component, event, helper) {
  let data = component.get("v.lineitems");
  let index = event.target.get("v.ariaLabel");
  let booleanCheck = true;
  if(booleanCheck) {
    data[index].isLineItemChecked = false;
    component.set("v.lineitems", data);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

I took some liberties in the above code, since we don't have a complete picture, but this is how you'd address updating the checkbox value.